How to implement a Lie bracket in Mathematica by specifying its properties and action on generators?
I want to implement a Lie bracket operation in Mathematica and don't know exactly how to do it. What I want is something like:

I prescribe a set of generators L[m]

I then define some bracket operation Bracket[X,Y] by specifying
(a) It must be bilinear;
(b) It must be skew-symmetric
(c) The brackets of the L[m] are given by some structure constants
Bracket[L[m],L[n]] = Sum[C[m,n,k] L[k],{k,0,N] 



A concrete example would be the Witt algebra where we have L[m] for any integer m and then we would like to impose the brackets of generators Bracket[L[m],L[n]]=(m-n)L[m+n].
Now the thing is that I don't know how to specify a function by properties it satisfies plus its values in some basic elements like this.
What is the simplest way to implement something like this in mathematica?

For what are you using this? Do you want to be express elements as linear combinations of the generators, then be able to multiply them and have Mathematica simplify them according to Lie bracket rules, ending up with an expression written as a linear combination of the generators? (Or are the Lie bracket rules enough to be able to take a product of elements written as linear combinations of the generators and simplify the product into a linear combination of the generators? That's unclear to me actually.)

Or is it enough to just be able to simplify the Lie bracket of two elements into a linear combination of the generators?

Could set up down values like so.
bracket[a_*ll[m_Integer], bb_] := a*bracket[ll[m], bb]
bracket[aa_, b_*ll[m_Integer]] := b*bracket[aa, ll[m]]
bracket[aa_ + bb_, ll[m_Integer]] := 
 bracket[aa, ll[m]] + bracket[bb, ll[m]]
bracket[ll[m_Integer], aa_ + bb_] := 
 bracket[ll[m], aa] + bracket[ll[m], bb]
bracket[aa_, bb_] /; FreeQ[aa, ll[_]] || FreeQ[bb, ll[_]] := 0
bracket[ll[m_Integer], ll[m_]] := 0
bracket[ll[m_Integer], ll[n_Integer]] /; 
  n < m := -bracket[ll[n], ll[m]]
bracket[ll[m_Integer], ll[n_Integer]] /; n > m := ll[m + n]

Some quick tests.
bracket[x, y]

(* Out[77]= 0 *)

bracket[x*ll[1], y*ll[2]]

(* Out[76]= x y ll[3] *)

bracket[x*ll[1], y*ll[2] + z*ll[0]]

(* Out[78]= x (-z ll[1] + y ll[3]) *)


Here is a start for what you might want. Define a list of replacement rules that implement bilinearity, the alternating property, and the rules for the generators:
bracketRules = {bracket[a_ + b_, c_] :> bracket[a, c] + bracket[b, c],
   bracket[a_, b_ + c_] :> bracket[a, b] + bracket[a, c],
   bracket[a_, a_] :> 0,
   bracket[x_L a_ /; FreeQ[a, L], b_] :> a bracket[x, b],
   bracket[b_, x_L a_ /; FreeQ[a, L]] :> a bracket[b, x],
   bracket[L[m_], L[n_]] :> (m - n) L[m + n]
   (*,bracket[L[m_],L[n_]]:>Sum[C[m,n,k]L[k],{k,0,nn}]*)
 };

Here, I've done it specifically for the Witt algebra, but there is a commented-out line where a more general bracket rule is defined.
We can then use ReplaceRepeated (//.) to apply these rules to a Lie bracket of two sums over the generators:
Collect[bracket[Sum[a[j] L[j], {j, 1, 2}], Sum[b[j] L[j], {j, 1, 3}]] //. bracketRules, _L]
(* (a[2] b[1] - a[1] b[2]) L[3] - 2 a[1] b[3] L[4] - a[2] b[3] L[5] *)


@user1620696 There is also apparently a third-party package called LieART that someone has written and maintained (at least until 2020). I've never used it though, so I don't know if it has the kind of functionality that you want.
